# Embed API -> Multiple Dimensions through Datatable

Tags: javascript, api, google-analytics, embed

Can some help me debugging my code? I want to have multiple dimensions in my Google Chart with data from Google Analytics. I would like to have a line chart with x-axis: date and 2 data (unique users & App Version). I have this code:

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

    /**
     * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
     * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
     * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
     */
    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
      container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
      clientid: 'XXX'
    });


    /**
     * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
     * element with the id "view-selector-container".
     */
    var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
      container: 'view-selector-container'
    });

    // Render the view selector to the page.
    viewSelector.execute();

    /**
     * Reports.
     */

    var report = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
      query: {
          ids: 'ga:104696078',
          metrics: 'ga:users',
          dimensions: 'ga:date,ga:operatingSystem',
          'start-date': '30daysAgo',
          'end-date': 'yesterday'
      }
  });

  report.on('success', function handleCoreAPIResponse(resultsAsObject) {

      if (resultsAsObject.rows.length > 0) {

         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          data.addColumn('string', 'date');
          data.addColumn('string', 'operatingSystem');
          data.addColumn('number', 'users'); 

          resultsAsObject.rows.forEach(function pushNumericColumn(row) {

              data.addRow([row[0], parseInt(row[1])]);

          }); 

          var options = {
              title: 'Custom Chart',
          };

          var chart = new    google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById("chart_div"));
          chart.draw(data, options);
      }
  });
  });
```

Comment: It seems like you followed the example here http://www.yourcloudbuddy.com/2015/03/the-easy-way-getting-data-out-from-google-analytics.html

You are on the right trakt, but you still need to include the data (e.g. number of users) in the 
    data.addRow([row[0], parseInt(row[1])]);
line.